# Constructing DArray from multidimensional Array locally

Tags: julia

I need to create DArray in such a way that every original row from Array must be available from a worker process. 
How can I avoid broadcasting multidimmensional Array to all workers when creating a DArray?

Consider the example code:

```
@everywhere X = ones(10000000, 3) #a. making X variable available to all processes

da = @DArray [X[i,:] for i = 1:size(X,1)] #b. creating DArray, so that the entire X row is held on the worker process
```

How can I avoid the a. step since the X data can be very huge?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will work for you, but have you considered initializing `X` as a `SharedArray` instead? That way it'll be available to all worker processes.

Comment: It should run on one machine (not checked), but ultimately I think of a cluster of machines.

Comment: Dear Nils, please have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656858/parallelising-gradient-calculation-in-julia/32166612#32166612). I followed your advice and initialize it locally. It's not the answer to my question of course, but it is related to your proposal.